# I want to create a highchart, where by default it will show the data in hours format, and when zoomed it will show in minutes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have data, where I have data of how many people visited the website per minute.
Here are my points while using highchart

1. chart type is "COLUMN"
2. by default the xAxis is shown in hour
3. with zoom feature enabled, when i select one of the column, the data will expand to "minute"

[Per hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIIwq.png)

[When selected one oh them and then changed to minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU4GZ.png)

I tried this:

```
`const eventData = [
  [Date.UTC(2023, 0, 1, 0), 10],
  [Date.UTC(2023, 0, 1, 1), 15],
  [Date.UTC(2023, 0, 1, 2), 8],
  // Add more data points as needed
];

// Function to convert events per hour to events per minute
function eventsPerMinute(data) {
  return data.map(point => [point[0], point[1] / 60]);
}

// Create the chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    zoomType: 'x' // Enable zoom
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Event Count Chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      hour: '%H:%M',
      minute: '%H:%M'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Events'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Events per Hour',
    data: eventData,
    pointInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000, // Interval in milliseconds (1 hour)
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2023, 0, 1, 0), // Starting point (00:00)
  }]
});

// Handle the selection event for zooming
function handleZoom(event) {
  if (event.resetSelection) {
    // Reset to original data when zoom is reset
    chart.series[0].setData(eventData);
    chart.xAxis[0].update({
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        hour: '%H:%M'
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Convert to events per minute and update x-axis format
    chart.series[0].setData(eventsPerMinute(eventData));
    chart.xAxis[0].update({
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        minute: '%H:%M'
      }
    });
  }
}

chart.options.chart.events = {
  selection: handleZoom
};`
```

But zoom is not working

Comment: what happens when you use wheel to zoom in? did you check the console what happens?

Comment: Hi, I don't fully get the 'per Minute" concept, however, I prepared the example of using a selection event in your case: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w8dyuapq/  Let me know if that is what you were looking for.